# C#, Catch Exception

Tags: c#, exception

I get a Exception type using

```
catch(Exception e){
  log.Error(e.GetType()); // it write 'System.Data.EntityException'
}
```

so I change my code to catch that exception,

```
try{
...
}catch(EntityException a){
  // need to do something
  log.Error("I got it!");
}catch(Exception e){
  log.Error("No");
}
```

and the code write only "No".

How can I catch the EntityException before reach Exception?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that there is not other EntityException? try `throw new System.Data.EntityException();` directly and see if it is caught.

Comment: try getting the type of the exception inside your second catch block, is it still EntityException?

Comment: Your code snippet must work. Tell us more information, or put the full typename together with the "No" string...

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `catch(System.Data.EntityException a)`

Comment: append the exception type to the end of you control string:  `"I got it! " + a.GetType().ToString()` and `e.GetType().ToString()`... just to verify that when the bottom-most catch is invoked it really is getting what you believe its getting.

Comment: Is `EntityException` a `System.Data.EntityException`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have *should* work correctly, provided there isn't another `EntityException` type defined within the current set of using statements for that file or namespace.

Try fully qualifying the type, as in the following:

```
try{
...
}catch(System.Data.EntityException a){
  // need to do something
  log.Error("I got it!");
}catch(Exception e){
  log.Error("No");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and the accepted answer here wasn't working for me. While EntityException is fully qualified as System.Data.EntityException, it's actually in the System.Data.Entity assembly (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entityexception(v=vs.110).aspx), so the project needs a reference to System.Data.Entity before Intellisense will recognize System.Data.EntityException in your code.

Comment: (+1) System.Data.EntityException was not working for me either. This Question answers the same problem: [Handle exceptions in entity framework 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042107/handle-exceptions-in-entity-framework-4)

Answer (score -1):

The first 'catch' to match the exception is the one that is activated.

Comment: -1 - this is exactly what OP asks - it should, but apparently does not in that particular case.