Can't use Tempdata in The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint,
I try to delete the product and display the error message when the product still related to many tables in database. Here the code :
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    if (_context.Products == null)
    {
        return Problem("Entity set 'ShoeContext.Products'  is null.");
    }
    var product = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
    if (product != null)
    {
        _context.Products.Remove(product);
        try
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException?.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx)
            {
                TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Cant't Delete This Product";
                return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
            }
            throw;
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

In Index.cshtml :
@if (TempData["ErrorMessage"] != null)
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @TempData["ErrorMessage"]
    </div>
}

But Its alway show like this img . I already use UseSession in Program.cs
 builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
 {
     options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
     options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;// Set the session timeout as needed
     options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
 });

Does anyone know the problem ? Did I use tempdata or try catch in the wrong way? I really appreciated any instruction. Thank You

If you debug your code, you might well find that either 1) The exception being thrown isn't a DbUpdateException, or 2) The DbUpdateException.InnerException.InnerException isn't an SqlException. Why not break out the debugger and take a look?

(Note that https://stackoverflow.com/a/25937584/1086121 recommends using GetBaseException(), rather than trying to guess the right number of InnerExceptions)

So you have other stuff that depends on Product, like maybe the sales history.. You download a product only, with none of the related data, and then try to delete it - if the db relationships don't cascade than the database will complain, but EF didn't know it had to delete the related data too. You either download all related data so that EF knows what relations it has to delete (or sever), or you configure your refs to cascade on the DB side, then EF can delete the parental Product and the database cleans up. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete

could you try debug the application to check that the session is being set correctly and that the TempData value is being assigned and retained through the redirect.try to set the code catch (DbUpdateException ex){     if (ex.InnerException?.InnerException is SqlException sqlEx && sqlEx.Number == 547) // SQL Error Code for Constraint Violation     {         TempData["ErrorMessage"] = "Can't delete this product";         return RedirectToAction("Index");      }     throw; }
